# Copy string to clipboard with hidden field

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to copy a parameter string into my clipboard using native JS. This works fine so far, however I have a small cosmetic problem, when running my snippet in IE 7.

My code:

```
function copyStringToClipboard (str) {
    // Create new element
    var el = document.createElement('input');
    el.setAttribute("display", "none");
    el.setAttribute("type", "text");
    el.value = str;
    el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    el.select();
    // Copy text to clipboard
    document.execCommand('copy');
    // Remove temporary element
    document.body.removeChild(el);
}
```

As I mentioned above, this *does* work in the tested browsers. However, it creates a **visible** text-input field (line 3). I tried  using `el.style = {position: 'absolute', left: '-9999px'};`, but Internet Explorer yields:

> Not implemented

I thought about creating an `input type="hidden"`, but it seems like this hidden field is not selectable - which makes sense. Needlessly to say, that this action triggers `onClick()`, so indeed with an user-action.

Ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `el.setAttribute("display", "none");`, You should change that line to:

```
el.style.display = "none";
```

**Why this works?** 
Setting the attribute display none does not affect the style. It should be added as inline style or in the css to hide the input box.